# Предзаполнение БД Postgres в тестконтейнере с помощью DbUnit в интегротестах

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

Всем привет.

Стек: Java 17, Spring Boot 3.1.2, DbUnit 2.7.3

Пытаюсь написать интегротест, который поднимет тестконтейнер с postgres, запустит миграцию liquibase и создаст нужные таблицы,
а затем с помощью аннотации @DatabaseSetup наполнит таблицу дефолтными данными описанными в xml-датасете.

Мой датасет:

```
<dataset>
    <shop id="TESTID" shop_type="Type1" has_source="false" version="2" group="TestGroup"/>
</dataset>
```

Проблема следующая: в таблице есть столбец "group" - а это зарезервированное слово.
Если оставить как есть, при запуске выдает ошибку:
**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"**

Нашел [вот такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728005/escaping-reserved-keywords-in-dbunit-for-db2) решение, но не помогает.
В датасете обернул group

```
<shop id="TESTID" shop_type="Type1" has_source="false" version="2" `group`="TestGroup"/>
```

В конфигурацию теста добавил configBean.setEscapePattern();

```
        @Bean 
        DatabaseConfigBean configBean() {
            final var configBean = new DatabaseConfigBean();
            configBean.setDatatypeFactory(new PostgreDataTypeFactory());
//пробовал по разному
//            configBean.setEscapePattern("[?]");
//            configBean.setEscapePattern("[group]");
            configBean.setEscapePattern("`?`");
            return configBean;
        }

        @Bean DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean dbUnitDatabaseConnection(DatabaseConfigBean configBean,
                                                                               DataSource dataSource) {
            final var factoryBean = new DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setDatabaseConfig(configBean);
            factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factoryBean.setSchema("mySchemeName");
            return factoryBean;
        }
```

**org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: Line 2: Element type "shop" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".**

Что делаю не так?

Comment: В xml уберите кавычки у `\`group\`` , и попробуйте еще раз. Указанная ошибка ругается на неправильный xml, а не на зарезервированное слово.

Comment: без кавычек ошибка, которая описана выше:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"

Comment: Тогда стоит попробовать паттерн как указано по ссылке в ответе `setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_ESCAPE_PATTERN, "\"?\"");`.  Постгре умеет экранировать ключевые слова двойными кавычками, напр. `select * from "shop";` и `select * from shop` одинаково воспринимает. Для mysql другой символ экранирования `\`` , одинарная кавычка.

Comment: если сделать такой паттерн
configBean.setEscapePattern("\?"\"");

и оставить в xml
group="TestGroup"

будет первоначальная ошибка
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"